# How much is Plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers, fractions

What does plural mean? Is it 2 or greater?

Is 1.5 plural? Is it "I ate 1.5 apple." or "I ate 1.5 apples."?

Comment: You seems to be asking whether _plural_ applies to fractions greater than 1 but less than 2 or only to integers greater than 1. But if your dictionary defines _plural_ as meaning "more than one"—which is something you can look up for yourself—the question logically comes down to asking whether 1.5 (for example) is "more than one," doesn't it?

Comment: I would go further and say that any quantity, amount, etc, expressed in in decimal form,  that is not exactly equal to one, is plural - so 1.5 apples, 0.5 tons of coal, 0.25 miles, etc. Most people don't actually talk in decimals in general conversation or writing, though.

Comment: "I ate an apple and a half" OR "I ate one-and-a-half apples".